# Logout after the Timer Expires

Tags: javascript

I am using the below to count milliseconds, it works perfectly well. But I want to call a logout() when the timer value is 9 seconds. It does not work. Can you anyone suggest ?

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer, time = 0, start_time = 0;
function startstoptimer() 
{
   if (timer)
   {
      time += new Date().getTime() - start_time;
      start_time = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;
   } 
   else 
   {
     start_time = new Date().getTime();
     timer = setInterval(function () 
     {

        document.d.d2.value = (time + new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000;
        if((time + new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000==9.000)
            logout();  
      }, 10);
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function logout() 
{
alert('Time is up');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using `==` may be a problem. For example if your timer gose from `8.995` seconds to `9.005` seconds, it skipped pass `9.000`. I would change it to `... >= 9.000`. Also you don't need the extra `<script>` tag. And how is the timer called?

Comment: Where do you call startstoptimer?

Comment: @Paddy onLoad=startstoptimer()

Comment: I believe the running script each 10 miliseconds to check if 9 seconds passed is not very productive. Otherwise you should start 9 seconds timeout after some last action event (eg. mouse move or key press) and reset it each time some action was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of unprecise floating point number comparisons, you cannot predict if the comparison can fail due truncation/precision errors caused by floating point arithmetics, I would avoid trust that

This is what I would do:

```
function startstoptimer() 
{
   if (timer)
   {
      time += new Date().getTime() - start_time;
      start_time = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
      clearTimeout(launchLogoutTimer); // clear timeout
      timer = null;
   } 
   else 
   {
     start_time = new Date().getTime();
     timer = setInterval(function () 
     {

        document.d.d2.value = (time + new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000;
        /*if((time + new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000==9.000)
            logout();// dont call logout here  */
     }, 10);
     // this way, you will be sure logout will be called after 9 seconds
     // (unless you cancel it before using clearTimeout)
     launchLogoutTimer = setTimeout(logout, 9000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! that works well !! just that the logout triggers after few millisecods i.e 9.032, 9.024